# Instantiating one class or another inside another class

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a JS Module to handle data persistence. There's a high level class that checks for the existence of window.localStorage, and, depending on the result, sets a storage variable to be an instance of one of two classes: LocalStorage and MemoryStorage.
The LocalStorage class has the storage injected on the constructor, so it can be flexible and tested.
While I have something that works, it doesn't feel optimized to me. Is there any better way of doing this?

```
class Storage {
  constructor() {
    this.storage = window.localStorage ? new LocalStorage(window.localStorage) : memoryStorage
  }
}

export default class LocalStorage {
  constructor(storage) {
    // The ternary isn't that relevant. I didn't put much thought into it yet
    this.storage = storage ? storage : {};
  }
}

class MemoryStorage {
  constructor() {
  }
}
export const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
```

I'd like this to be improved, but also understand why, as it doesn't feel right.

Comment: Why can't you make ```LocalStorage``` and ```MemoryStorage``` to be two separate methods inside the ```Storage``` class

Comment: "Optimized" how? If the point is to have a unified interface then 'storage' should be in the base class and and methods delegated to an implementation instance. Or just have a factory that returns an instance of the appropriate implementation.

Comment: Yes, you've definitely got too many storages in your code (`localstorage`, `memorystorage`, `Storage`, `Storage.storage`, `LocalStorage`, `LocalStorage.storage` and that object literal). But it's not clear from the code at all what you need. Please tell us which functionalities all of these storages provides, and possible how they are implemented. Currently, all we could tell you is to drop all of them.

Comment: Well, memory storage is a fallback, in case there's no local storage. It's a simple map. The localstorage class is the one that directly interacts with the actual localstorage.
Finally, the Storage, is an abstraction layer, which should logically define which type of storage to use (memory or local). Using the Storage class should be isent from specifying which store to use.

The usage should be pretty simple. Just setting and getting values from the storage.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a factory which executed a function that would evaluate which type of storage is available, prioritizing LocalStorage, while both LocalStorage and MemoryStorage extended the Storage class.